# Matplotlib/pyplot: Auto adjust unit of y Axis

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to modify the Y axis unit of the plot indicated below. Preferable would be the use of units like *M* (Million), *k* (Thousand) for large numbers. For example, the y Axis should look like: 50k, 100k, 150k, etc.

The plot below is generated by the following code snippet:

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both')
plt.title("TTL Distribution")
plt.xlabel('TTL Value')
plt.ylabel('Number of Packets')
y = graphy  # data from a sqlite query
x = graphx  # data from a sqlite query
width = 0.5
plt.bar(x, y, width, align='center', linewidth=2, color='red', edgecolor='red')
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25119872/3017719) post and thought I could write my own formatting function:

```
def y_fmt(x, y):
    if max_y > 1000000:
        val = int(y)/1000000
        return '{:d} M'.format(val)
    elif max_y > 1000:
        val = int(y) / 1000
        return '{:d} k'.format(val)
    else:
        return y
```

But I missed that there is no `plt.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(y_fmt))` function available for the bar plot I am using.

**How I can achieve a better formatting of the Y axis?**

[[image: TTL Distribution Plot]]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In principle there is always the option to set custom labels via `plt.gca().yaxis.set_xticklabels()`.

However, I'm not sure why there shouldn't be the possibility to use [`matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) here. The `FuncFormatter` is designed for exactly the purpose of providing custom ticklabels depending on the ticklabel's position and value. 
There is actually a [nice example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html) in the matplotlib example collection.

In this case we can use the FuncFormatter as desired to provide unit prefixes as suffixes on the axes of a matplotlib plot. To this end, we iterate over the multiples of 1000 and check if the value to be formatted exceeds it. If the value is then a whole number, we can format it as integer with the respective unit symbol as suffix. On the other hand, if there is a remainder behind the decimal point, we check how many decimal places are needed to format this number.

Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def y_fmt(y, pos):
    decades = [1e9, 1e6, 1e3, 1e0, 1e-3, 1e-6, 1e-9 ]
    suffix  = ["G", "M", "k", "" , "m" , "u", "n"  ]
    if y == 0:
        return str(0)
    for i, d in enumerate(decades):
        if np.abs(y) >=d:
            val = y/float(d)
            signf = len(str(val).split(".")[1])
            if signf == 0:
                return '{val:d} {suffix}'.format(val=int(val), suffix=suffix[i])
            else:
                if signf == 1:
                    print val, signf
                    if str(val).split(".")[1] == "0":
                       return '{val:d} {suffix}'.format(val=int(round(val)), suffix=suffix[i]) 
                tx = "{"+"val:.{signf}f".format(signf = signf) +"} {suffix}"
                return tx.format(val=val, suffix=suffix[i])

                #return y
    return y


fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(10,5))

x = np.linspace(0,349,num=350) 
y = np.sinc((x-66.)/10.3)**2*1.5e6+np.sinc((x-164.)/8.7)**2*660000.+np.random.rand(len(x))*76000.  
width = 1

ax[0].bar(x, y, width, align='center', linewidth=2, color='red', edgecolor='red')
ax[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(y_fmt))

ax[1].bar(x[::-1], y*(-0.8e-9), width, align='center', linewidth=2, color='orange', edgecolor='orange')
ax[1].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(y_fmt))

ax[2].fill_between(x, np.sin(x/100.)*1.7+100010, np.cos(x/100.)*1.7+100010, linewidth=2, color='#a80975', edgecolor='#a80975')
ax[2].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(y_fmt))

for axes in ax:
    axes.set_title("TTL Distribution")
    axes.set_xlabel('TTL Value')
    axes.set_ylabel('Number of Packets')
    axes.set_xlim([x[0], x[-1]+1])

plt.show()
```

which provides the following  plot:

[image]

Comment: Nice example, lot more complete than mine. But you write *"if there is a remainder behind the decimal point, we check how many decimal places are needed"*, but the cut-off is still a bit random? E.g. `y_fmt(100100, 0)` returns `100.1 k` but `y_fmt(100010, 0)` returns `100 k`.

Comment: @Bart Correct! I did think of that problem, but forgot about it afterwards. I updated the example to include such cases, where numbers are big but also close to each other.

Comment: There is also the built in `EngFormatter` which does something very similar out of the box http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/engineering_formatter.html

Comment: @tacaswell That's great! In which version was that introduced? The [normal api doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) doesn't have it (yet?).

Answer (score 5):

You were pretty close; one (possibly) confusing thing about `FuncFormatter` is that the first argument is the tick value, and the second the tick position , which (when named `x,y`) can be confusing for the y-axis. For clarity, I renamed them in the example below.

> The function should take in two inputs (tick value x and position pos) and return a string

(http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter)

Working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import matplotlib.ticker as tick

def y_fmt(tick_val, pos):
    if tick_val > 1000000:
        val = int(tick_val)/1000000
        return '{:d} M'.format(val)
    elif tick_val > 1000:
        val = int(tick_val) / 1000
        return '{:d} k'.format(val)
    else:
        return tick_val

x = np.arange(300)
y = np.random.randint(0,2000000,x.size)

width = 0.5
pl.bar(x, y, width, align='center', linewidth=2, color='red', edgecolor='red')
pl.xlim(0,300)

ax = pl.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(y_fmt))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! However, the answer from ImportanceOfBeingErnest additionally extends the suffixes thus I marked it as 'accepted'.