# How to do I change the y-axis number to be millions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using MatPlotLib, I was able to import data from the US Census, comparing New York's population growth to Florida's. The program works, but I want to change the y-axis numbers to reflect the growth in millions. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(18, 16), dpi= 100, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(content.loc[10, ['1910_POPULATION', '1920_POPULATION', 
'1930_POPULATION', '1940_POPULATION', '1950_POPULATION', 
'1960_POPULATION', '1970_POPULATION', '1980_POPULATION','1990_POPULATION', 
'2000_POPULATION']])

plt.plot(content.loc[33, ['1910_POPULATION', '1920_POPULATION', 
'1930_POPULATION', '1940_POPULATION', '1950_POPULATION', 
'1960_POPULATION', '1970_POPULATION', '1980_POPULATION','1990_POPULATION', 
'2000_POPULATION']])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566413/matplotlib-pyplot-auto-adjust-unit-of-y-axis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib/pyplot: Auto adjust unit of y Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566413/matplotlib-pyplot-auto-adjust-unit-of-y-axis)

Comment: What exactly do you want the labels to look like? `'1 million'`? `'1m'`? Something else?

Comment: Just to number would be fine with me, but it would be nice to know how to change them in general.