# How to convert offset (1e6) to normal denomination ( 5M or 500K) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This might be similar to a question mentioned in the below post:
[matplotlib: format axis offset-values to whole numbers or specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number)

but I am writing this coz I tested solutions but nothing worked. I was unable to add comment on give solutions. So, please bear with me on this.

Here is the dataset: https://github.com/JordanTheDodger/Temp-Repo

```
gender_cases = df.groupby('gender').sum().sort_values(by='std_cases',ascending=False)
gender_cases = gender_cases.reset_index()

#plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
sb.barplot(data=gender_cases, x='gender',y='rate');
plt.title('STD Rate of Male vs Female',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Gender',fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Rate',fontsize=15);
```

[image]

From the plot picture the goal is to fix yticks to normal format (like 1M or 500K).
Here is the pic of one of the proposed solutions in the post noted above

[image]

Comment: Show your problematic attempt. Reduce to mcve. There is no need to ask me to download your dataset to illustrate the problem. Use numpy.random to create a minimal sample that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Sure I will do that

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: The solution from https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_ticker1.html
worked from @wwii solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566413/matplotlib-pyplot-auto-adjust-unit-of-y-axis)
Thanks